# QT dynamicly add label and position it

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, label, qt5

I have the following scenario I have an "add_Button", if you push it. It should add a QLabel and a line Edit and position it right the old label. This should be dynamic and I have to get the data from the line edit. How can I solve my Problem, I guess it's quite easy. A Code Snippet for an explanation would be really great. 
Best regards and thank you

Comment: i have no real clue how to start my code or what i need exactly. So you can say i have a push button and an idea ;) I am new to QT i need it for my Bachelorthesis

Comment: Posting of homework tasks to stackoverflow is not the best way.

And about question: you need to add horisontal layout on your form, then connect your button clicked() signal to the some slot, which will create QLabel and insert it to the layout. Thats all :)

Comment: well its not homework. i do this for a company. ok i get this and how to create a label dynamic and stick it to the layout? i did nearly everything with the designer before... thanks alot btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a horizontal layout to the ui
2. On push button clicked create a lable and a line edit and add it to the horizontal layout some thing like shown below

   ```
   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
   {
   QLabel *label =  new QLabel();
   label->setText("This is how i add a label");
   label->setMinimumWidth(100);// You can set other properties similarly
   QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
   ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(label);
   ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
   }
   ```
3. Similar questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734209/adding-a-label-to-a-widget)

Comment: ok one more question, how can i get the data from all the dynamic line edits? can i make them like a list in c++?

Comment: Yes, QList,QMap<>etc. And you can save the pointer to the line edit with QList<QLineEdit*>