# redirect the program output to a QLabel instead of the console

Tags: c++, qt

How can I get my data to show up in the window created below. This was a console application and everything works fine. I just want the output to be in the window created instead of the console.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QString>
#include "Prob3TableInherited.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Entering problem number 3" << endl;
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 6;

    Prob3TableInherited tab("Problem3.txt", rows, cols);
    const int *naugT = tab.getTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << naugT[i*cols + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    const int *augT = tab.getAugTable();
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
        {
            cout << augT[i*(cols + 1) + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // How can I pass the data?
    QString data("Need To Pass Data Here");

    //Create the Window Application
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label=new QLabel(data);

    //Make it visible
    label->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the label to the QApplication.
Take a look at this answer:

[Adding a label to a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734209/adding-a-label-to-a-widget/5735112#5735112)

Comment: Did you manage to get the label to show up inside the Qt window?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the output to be in the window created instead of the console

you can use QStringList and append the output to it instead of cout. For example, your first loop will look like

```
...
QStringList outputList;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        outputList << naugT[i*cols + j] << " ";
    }
    outputList << "\n";
}
outputList << "\n";
...
```

then you may add the list to your label as follows

```
QLabel * label = new QLabel(outputList.join(""));
```

which is the same as

```
QString data = outputList.join("");
QLabel * label = new QLabel(data);
```

Comment: I did what you said and the code would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget `QWidget *w = new QWidget()` and attach the label to him

```
 QLabel *label = new QLabel(w);
 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();
 label->setText("your data");
 layout->addWidget(label);
 setLayout(layout);
```

than show the widget `w->show()`